# Only the first figure in a section can be referenced

Tags: cross-referencing

I have some figures in each section and all of them are like :

```
\begin{figure}[h!] 
  \begin{center} 
  \subfloat{
  \includegraphics[width=0.52\textwidth]{....jpg}
  } 
 \subfloat{
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{....jpg}
  }  
  \end{center}
  \caption{some caption}
  \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Only the first figure in each section can be referenced. the others are defined as ??.
I only have this problem in texmaker in Windows. My code in latex works fine.
I tried double compiling, deleting the aux files, so on...
appreciate any hint on the reason of such strange behaviour

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Do you compile your document twice? Are your reference labels equal to figure labels?

Comment: labels are associated with captions. You have only provided one `\caption`. You need to provide a `\caption` and `\label` for each of your subfloats.

Comment: As everything was fine in linux, i reinstalled the texmaker in windows and reset the settings of texmaker. Now everything workes fine.